# Why user is undefined the session callback

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm currently building a sign-in/register for my project. I have successfully saved the user to the database when they register. Now the problem is I want to return a custom session to my client, so I use the session callback, but no matter what I do the user is always undefined.

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: { label: "username", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credetials) {
                if (!credetials?.username || !credetials?.password) {
                    throw new Error("Missing credentials");
                }

                const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: {
                        username: credetials.username,
                    },
                });

                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
                }

                const isMatch = await compare(
                    credetials.password,
                    user.password
                );

                if (isMatch) {
                    return user;
                }

                throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, user }) {
            console.log(user); //undefined
            return session;
        },
    },
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    pages: {
        signIn: "/",
    },
};
```

I want the session to have an id, username and image field.